# Web collect: make the record enter a journey right away

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, form, smart-capture

I have a web collect form and I need the inserted data to enter a journey. I'm basically trying to replicate the smart capture entry event.

The reason why I can't use a smart capture is that it seems to be an 'insert' only method. It doesn't allow to make an update on the DE when submitting data and it doesn't return any error page/message/alert when submitting data that's already been submitted. It just gets stuck and the submit doesn't work.

The upsert action and the error message would be available on a smart capture created with classic content. But I wouldn't be able to use it as a entry event in a journey then as it is not a cloudpage.

I wonder if there's a way to use the web collect and then make that record enter the journey right away. I need it to be realtime like it is with a smart capture entry event.

Is this possible?

Comment: you would have to make an api call to inject into a journey

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's possible, but it's not an OOTB feature:

You could make an API call from your processing page and pass all the contact details into journey builder: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_jb_admit_contacts_via_api.htm&type=5

So here's a high-level setup:

1. Create a journey with an API event entry source
2. Install the managed package for use with API in SFMC and get the credentials:  https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/index-api.htm
3. Add an API call to your processing cloud page. You will first need to [authenticate](https://sfmarketing.cloud/2019/09/27/salesforce-marketing-cloud-api-authentication-using-server-side-javascript/) using the credentials and then pass subscriber data into the journey:

`

```
POST https://{{mc_subdomain}}.rest.marketingcloudapis.com/interaction/v1/events
Content-Type: application/json
Authorization: Bearer {{AccessToken}}

{
    "ContactKey": "123456",
    "EventDefinitionKey": "APIEvent-0dbe46de-74f9-a309-7778-298c0a565f93",
    "Data": {
        "SubscriberKey": "123456",
        "Email": "test@example.com"
    }
}
```

Read more here: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/how-to-fire-an-event.htm